# Javascript : Update timeout without re-creating it

Tags: javascript, timeout

I would like to know if there is a better way to update a JS Timeout without having to recreate it.

For exemple I have something like this :

```html
<input type="text" onchange="doSomething">
```

and in my script I am doing this :

```js
let activeTimeout = null
let doSomething = (event) => {
    if( activeTimeout !== null) clearTimeout(activeTimeout)
    activeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(event.target.value) // → Here i'm doing an XHR request to an API
        activeTimeout = null
    }, 2000)
}
```

So as you can see, I have to destroy the timeout and recreate it. I tried to do a `console.log(activeTimeout)` but it gives me a number, maybe an ID, so I was wondering if there was no way to do something like :

```js
let activeTimeout = null
let doSomething = (event) => {
    if( activeTimeout !== null) {
        window.timeouts[activeTimeout].time = 2000
    } else {
        activeTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(event.target.value) // → Here i'm doing an XHR request to an API
            activeTimeout = null
        }, 2000)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your recommendations.

Bye

Comment: Is there something wrong about your approach when recreating the timer? Or what's the reasoning behind finding an alternate solution?

Comment: Why not use a promise for the XHR? Then the timeout isn't needed.

Comment: You can do it in [node](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_refresh) but in browser you're stuck with cancel/recreate. Timeout id is an integer but you don't have direct access to the timers queue.

Comment: The simple answer is no. There's no standard way to change the expiration time of an existing timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) I was wondering the fact that there was no solution, but maybe I was wrong and could not find the solution on the internet ... that's why I asked

Comment: @evolutionxbox To explain better my code, I am doing the onchange function of an Input, every time the users change the input, I want to do a XHR Request to save the data he did write... But I don't want to have a request every character so I put a timeout to listen when the user pause, and if the pause is more than 2sec (in real life I put it to 1sec) I do the POST request to save it :) So I don't understand How a Promise could resolve my case ? Thx